# InvalidArgumentError: Cannot update variable with shape [] using a Tensor with shape [32]

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, nsl

I am trying to get started with Neural Structured Learning but when I run the example given on the page to test, I get the following error

I have tried to squeeze the dimensions, I have tried a different version of tensorflow --- I am still quite new to tensorflow so at this point I would really be guessing.

```
# Create a base model -- sequential, functional, or subclass.
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input((28, 28), name='feature'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

# Wrap the model with adversarial regularization.
adv_config = nsl.configs.make_adv_reg_config(multiplier=0.2, adv_step_size=0.05)
adv_model = nsl.keras.AdversarialRegularization(model, adv_config=adv_config)


# Compile, train, and evaluate.
adv_model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])


#let us now fit the model
adv_model.fit({'feature': x_train, 'label': y_train}, batch_size=32, epochs=5)



W0906 13:48:30.427690 140388427564928 training_utils.py:1101] Output output_1 missing from loss dictionary. We assume this was done on purpose. The fit and evaluate APIs will not be expecting any data to be passed to output_1.
Epoch 1/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-a5b951c24c49> in <module>()
----> 1 adv_model.fit({'feature': x_train, 'label': y_train}, batch_size=32, epochs=5)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot update variable with shape [] using a Tensor with shape [32], shapes must be equal.
     [[{{node AdversarialRegularization_1/AssignAddVariableOp_2}}]]
```

The model is supposed to train and I get some accuracy from it. I don't understand where the problem is from in my code.

I am running this on Google Colab with Tensorflow v1.14.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not mentioned explicitly in any requirements, in [all](https://www.tensorflow.org/neural_structured_learning/tutorials/adversarial_keras_cnn_mnist) [three](https://www.tensorflow.org/neural_structured_learning/tutorials/graph_keras_lstm_imdb) (so far) [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/neural_structured_learning/tutorials/graph_keras_mlp_cora), the first step is to install Tensorflow 2.0:

[image]

There is also a report of an error identical to yours in the relevant [blog post](https://medium.com/@amalvnair95/i-tried-out-example-code-for-mnist-and-i-get-the-following-error-9f7ff01f52e0), which was [resolved](https://medium.com/p/9f7ff01f52e0/responses/show) by upgrading to Tensorflow 2.0

So, make an environment where you install TF 2.0 and the package:

```
pip install --quiet tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0
pip install --quiet neural-structured-learning
```

and you should be fine.